# Can't set timeout longer than 30s for Google Cloud/App Engine tasks

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, task, google-cloud-tasks

I have a task I am running with Google App Engine/Cloud Tasks (as documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-appengine-tasks)) which uses Python 3.7 and could in some cases take up to a few hours to complete.

As such, I am trying to extend the default timeout length for the task.

Consulting the [documentation for the Python CloudTasksClient library](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/cloudtasks/latest/google.cloud.tasks_v2beta3.services.cloud_tasks.CloudTasksClient#google_cloud_tasks_v2beta3_services_cloud_tasks_CloudTasksClient_create_task), its shown that the `create_task` method has a `timeout` parameter which is a float. What's not explained is what the default value is, what unit (e.g. seconds, minutes) it is, or what the maximum it can be set to is.

I tried setting `timeout` to 86400 (aka 24 hours) and got the following error:

`The request deadline is 2023-05-25T11:49:43.227120541-07:00. The deadline cannot be more than 30s in the future.`

This doesn't make any sense to me — why should a task be limited to taking longer than 30 seconds? We use manual scaling in the Standard environment, so according to [this](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-appengine-handlers) in the docs the timeout should be extendable up to 24 hours.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: can you add the code how do you create the task? thanks

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko Code is pretty much exactly the same as this example: https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-appengine-tasks

Comment: One exception is we are not using `schedule_time`

Comment: Since it's a float, try ```86400.0```. What you currently have might be interpreted as an integer by the library

Comment: Got the same error trying the float value @NoCommandLine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help

1. `timeout.py` (google/api_core/timeout.py) has the following piece of code

   ```
    class TimeToDeadlineTimeout(object):
    """A decorator that decreases timeout set for an RPC based on how much time
    has left till its deadline. The deadline is calculated as
    ``now + initial_timeout`` when this decorator is first called for an rpc.

    In other words this decorator implements deadline semantics in terms of a
    sequence of decreasing timeouts t0 > t1 > t2 ... tn >= 0.

    Args:
        timeout (Optional[float]): the timeout (in seconds) to applied to the
            wrapped function. If `None`, the target function is expected to
            never timeout.
    """
   ```
2. From the above, a possible solution to your problem (providing enough time for your long running task to end) would be to supply a value of `None` to the timeout. I tested with a value of None and didn't receive an error i.e. the following code was successful

   `client.create_task(parent=parent, task=task, timeout=None)`
3. If you must provide a value for the timeout, it looks like it can't be more than 30 seconds (this is the default value as seen in `_DEFAULT_MAXIMUM_TIMEOUT = 30.0  # seconds` which can be found in `timeout.py`

Comment: Thanks, tried the None argument and that worked, at least for tasks up to 10 minutes! Additionally I'm realizing i had to update the instance class and scaling type for the worker

Answer (score 0):

The deadline varies for different targets [according to the docs](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.queues.tasks#Task.FIELDS.dispatch_deadline):

- for HTTP target it's 30 minutes
- for AppEngine target it's either 60 mins (Flex) or 24 hours (Standard)

So now it depends what the target of your task is. If it's HTTP, maybe the value 30 is correct, but they got the units in the error message wrong (seconds instead of minutes)?

Please provide more details about what how does your task look exactly.

Comment: The target is an AppEngine worker, and as I mentioned we are using the standard environment. We're creating an "App Engine HTTP request" pretty much exactly as documented here: https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-appengine-tasks