# Google App Engine: DeadlineExceededError: The overall deadline for responding to the HTTP request was exceeded while reading fetching data

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I receive this error:

```
DeadlineExceededError: The overall deadline for responding to the HTTP request was exceeded
```

from `Google App Engine (GAE)` instance type `f` and runtime `python 2`

It probably happens because im trying to receive a massive amount of data from a persistence layer and the request times out.

Documentation says: The timeout for other HTTP requests is 1 minute
[How Instances are Managed](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed#instance_scaling)

Any possible ways to extend this timeout?

Comment: Timeout after 5 secondes?  It's not normal! are you sure?

Comment: After a couple of seconds. Have you dealt with this prob before?

Comment: By default, the deadline for a fetch is 5 seconds. You can change this default by Including the following [appengine.api.urlfetch.defaultDeadline](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref#urlfetch_timeout) setting in your appengine-web.xml configuration file. You can also adjust the default deadline by using the [urlfetch.set\_default\_fetch\_deadline()](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/issue-requests#setting_a_request_timeout) function.Refer this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70539968/18265638)

Comment: Its not about fetching a url but more about fetching a huge amount of data from a database and processing it. I neglected to mention that Im using GAE with python 2 runtime. Documentaion: The timeout for HTTP requests is 1 minute

Comment: Have a look at this stackoverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76361614/18265638) which might help

Comment: The root reason is that underlying infra is not enough, any timeout fix will not help as such. You can either raise the instance type (which give more memory+cpu) OR fetch the data in smaller sets ([cursor](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/samples/datastore-cursor-paging#datastore_cursor_paging-python) based).

Comment: @Vivek this is definitely not true

Comment: @panos : curious what part is not true? Did you then found what was actually causing DeadlineExceededError? Did you tried raising your instance type and it didn't worked? OP mentions HTTP requests, and my comment is in that direction, meaning if you want to solve by keeping in HTTP req way. However, if you switch to tasks that's all together a different approach.

Comment: @Vivek: im currently using f4 instances which have the ighest possible memory and cpu. The problem is what is mentioned below as an answer. The other thing is that I do need all the data and processing on it so I dont think that cursor would help. Nevertheless, thanks a lot for your reponse and it was actually right but my answer was a bit too harsh. Tasks indeed would be a possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any possible ways to extend this timeout?

Not directly. Your possible options are

1. Stay on Python 2 and switch to tasks which has a 10 minute timeout
2. Upgrade to Python 3 which also has a 10 minute timeout. **This is a better option** because you actually have to switch to Python 2 by Jan 30, 2024 ([see](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/lifecycle/support-schedule#python) end of support schedule for Python 2)